# convert factors to numeric in R: output depends on machine?

Tags: r

I'm converting some strings to numeric values on 3 different machines:

1) Computer_me: my computer, Ubuntu 18.04

2) Computer_colleague: Ubuntu 16.04

3) remote_server: Ubuntu 16.04

All the machines are accessing to the exact same dataset and executing the same script (shared folder).

The strings correspond to some unique ID, and for the analyses I need them to be numeric. I thus use the following:

```
ID_numeric = as.numeric(as.factor(ID_string))
```

The *ID_string vector* is the same on the 3 machines, but the *ID_numeric* obtained differs: it is similar on the two machines using Ubuntu 16.04 (i.e. *Computer_colleague* and *remote_server*), but is different on *Computer_me*.

I don't know if the problem is because of the different Linux version (that's the only explanation I can imagine so far), but is there a way to force as.numeric to return the same values independently of the machine used? (or a better way to make this conversion)

Thanks

Comment: Need to have as.character before as.numeric

Comment: if the unique ID strings are like "123456", perhaps `strtoi` would be a more platform-independent approach to converting characters to integers (or numeric).

Comment: my string are a combination of letters and numbers, so strtoi doesn't work fine.

Comment: ... and adding as.character just give me some NAs, I guess because of the same reason. (that's why I'm converting everything to factors befaore doing the conversion to integers)

Comment: Try `factor(ID_string,levels=sort(unique(ID_string)))`

Comment: The manual recommends `f <- as.factor(ID_string); as.numeric(levels(f))[f]` and says **In particular, ‘as.numeric’ applied to a factor is meaningless, and may happen by implicit coercion.**

Comment: the factor option and using levels do not work neither. The meaning of these values are not important, so I'm fine with that. The only purpose is to obtain numeric values between 1 and the number of levels in the factor. Anyway, I guess that the safest option is always to run this once on a a machine and save the result in a Rdata file